# sending notification to one user using Channels 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I want to send notification to specific authenticated user using Channels 2.

In below code i am sending notification as a broadcast instead of that i want to send notification to  a specific user.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer


class NotifyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.channel_layer.group_add("gossip", self.channel_name)
        print(f"Added {self.channel_name} channel to gossip")

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard("gossip", self.channel_name)
        print(f"Removed {self.channel_name} channel to gossip")

    async def user_gossip(self, event):
        await self.send_json(event)
        print(f"Got message {event} at {self.channel_name}")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most users new to Django-channels 2.x face this problem. let me explain.

`self.channel_layer.group_add("gossip", self.channel_name)` takes two arguments: **room_name** and **channel_name**

When you connect from your browser via `socket` to this consumer, you are creating a new socket connection called as `channel`. So, when you open multiple pages in your browser, multiple channels are created. Each channel has a unique Id/name : `channel_name`

`room` is a group of channels. If anyone sends a message to the `room`, all channels in that `room` will receive that message.

So, if you need to send a notification/message to a single user, then you must create a `room` only for that particular user.

Assuming that current `user` is passed in the consumer's `scope`.

```
self.user = self.scope["user"]
self.user_room_name = "notif_room_for_user_"+str(self.user.id) ##Notification room name
await self.channel_layer.group_add(
       self.user_room_name,
       self.channel_name
    )
```

Whenever you send/broadcast a message to `user_room_name`, It will only be received by that user.

Comment: HI.How can I send a broadcast a message to `user_room_name` from outside the Class,say a `view`? Thanks