# How to determine to message to particular set of listeners?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

How to determine to message to particular set of listeners?

For example, I have Luke,Jason and Bruce in ChatRoom A. Lisa in Chatroom B.And each member has a message list screen which only display the last message of group chat room.

I have a socket connection placed on every chatroom to listen incoming messages. Group messages from particular chatroom will have an room identifier along with message. The question is that how websocket to determine to send out messages only to those people who has subscribed to this chatroom?

This websocket conncetion will receive msgs from diffrent room but it needs only to send msgs out to those who belongs to that particular group chat room.

Do I need add some identifier in somewhere when I establish connection from client side so that serverside could know if it needs to send msgs to me?

Here is my connect function:

```
class GroupMessageListConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.userId = str(self.scope['query_string'])[2:-1].split("=")[1]

        # self.eventId = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['eventId']

        print('GroupMessageListConsumer connected self.userId:{}'.format(self.userId))

        # print('GroupMessageListConsumer connected self.userId:{}'.format(self.userId))
        # print('GroupMessageListConsumer connected self.eventId:{}'.format(self.eventId))

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.userId,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.userId,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

Comment: You need to pass along the `room identifier` along with the message. `{"room": 123, "message": "hi"}`. Then within your consumer's `receive` method check for appropriate room and pass on.

Comment: Can I set an identifier to websocket when it get establish? For example, pass an user.id to connect function. Therefore, I can check it later when I  received message from receive function to determine if I need to send out message for this particular user

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Within the `connect` method, you need to check and add the user to their respective rooms.

Comment: Do you know how can I pass some data to connect function when websocket get eastablished? I shall pass data as url parameters or in somewhere else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310717/sending-notification-to-one-user-using-channels-2/55311079#55311079

Comment: I passed userId as query_string attached to websocket url and assign it to self.userId. And I will also write some logic to receive function, receive function will receive data that contains roomId when clicent send data to it, I am going to use roomId  in receive function to find room members and only to broadcast to members that belongs to that particular room. I will try to loop roomMembers to see if self.userId in roomMembers and brocasting to client if find him/her. Do you think this logic is correct? Thank you.

Comment: And I have also paste some code that I used to get query_string from url. I realise it is a little weird solution to obtain query parameters but it working. Please also point out if I did some wrong here. I have added some code to clarify this question to above question block please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate Model `Room`

```
class Room(models.model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        "User",
        related_name='rooms',
        blank=True,
        symmetrical=False)
```

Before getting to `consumer.py`, Make sure your payload consists of these three:

`event_type`: What caused this event? a user is sending a message? you are sending a notification to a user? Is this an alert?

`data`: What data is sent along?

`errors`: Are there any errors?

Example payloads:

`{
    "event_type": "send_message",
    "data": {
            "message": "Hi",
            "room": 143,
        },
    "errors": None
}`

`{
    "event_type": "send_notif",
    "data": {
            "message": "You received a friend request from xxx",
            "type": "friend_request",
        },
    "errors": None
}`

Consumer.py

```
class GroupMessageListConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    user = None
    async def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope["user"] #authenticated user either passed in through session or by token authentication

        print("connection request received.")

        await self.accept()
        print("connection accepted")

        #channel/channel_name is the current open socket connection between your browser and the server

        # Join channel or user to his rooms
        for room in self.user.rooms:
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                room.id,
                self.channel_name
            )

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        #remove current channel from listening to messages as it is closed or disconnected
        # Leave channel from all rooms
        for room in self.user.rooms:
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                room.id,
                self.channel_name
            )
        print("channel disconnected.")
        raise StopConsumer()


    async def receive(self,text_data):
        print("message received.")
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        #always maintain payload with three main fields: "event_type", "data", "errors"
        event_type = text_data_json['event_type']
        data = text_data_json['data']
        if event_type=="send_message":
            #check whether user is allowed to send messages to room 143

            #Then send the message to that room.
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                data["room"],
                {
                    'type': "send_message", #call the respective event "async def send_message(self, event)" see below
                    'message': {
                        'event_type': event_type,
                        'data': {"message": data["message"], "user": self.user.id},
                        'errors': None
                    }
                }
            )
        else:
            print("event_type unknown")

    async def send_message(self, event):
        message =  event['message']
        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Comment: I didn't use django authentication module. My Django project act as backend Restful Api to serve my React Native front end project. So I think I didn't have user object in scope['user']. Can I pass it through web socket url as an parameter?

Comment: await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                room.id,
                self.channel_name
            )    self.channel_name is automatically generated by Django?  Can I use self.userId as channel_name?

Comment: @HExinhao No. In order to communicate via API, how are you authenticating a user? Anyone can access the endpoint? That will be a problem. Without authentication, I can send a message on behalf of you. Anyone will be able to do that.

Comment: Go through my answer here to understand the syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310717/sending-notification-to-one-user-using-channels-2/55311079#55311079

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will figure it out to use django authentication function later. Do you know how to pass parameter to websocket? And how to get it from connect function?